# ¿Cómo puedo sacar una variable de un bucle for y utilizarla de forma idependiente?

Tags: python, bucle-for, variables, diccionarios

Teniendo este código:

```
import json

tweets = open ('Tweets.txt')
found = 0
linea = 0
for line in tweets:
    contenido=json.loads(line)
    linea += 1
    if 'text' in contenido:   
        found += 1
        print("%3d %4d text=%s" % (found, linea, contenido['text']))
```

Megustaría extraer la variable contenido (dónde contiene los tweets) para así poder utilizarla en otro bucle con esta variable que muestro a continuación:

```
sentimientos = open("Sentimientos.txt") 
valores = {} 
for linea in sentimientos: 
    termino, valor = linea.split("\t") 
    valores[termino] = int(valor) 
print (valores.items() )
```

Que muestra un dict con el valor de palabras. De tal forma que puedas calcular el valor de cada tweet en función de la suma de los valores de las palabras que contenga cada tweet.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Entonces la idea es calcular el valor sentimental de cada `contenido['text']`y producir un diccionario valorizado?

Comment: ¿No valdrá más que en el bucle te limites a ir construyendo una lista con todos los contenidos? De ese modo, una vez finalices el bucle, aún tienes la lista que podrás recorrer y procesar cuantas veces necesites.

Comment: @Candid Moe eso es exactamente si.

Comment: @abulafia he intentado aprovechar el bucle pero no soy capaz de que me salga, además, prefiero contenterlo en una variable independiente para usarlo quizá más adelante para otro fines.

Comment: Pero eso es lo que yo te proponía, que tengas una variable global que sea una lista, cuyos elementos sean los "contenido" que extraes del json, y que esa lista la construyas en un bucle. ¿Qué es lo que tú quieres preservar para usar más adelante? ¿No era esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero construimos una función generadora. Esto es útil cuando se desea tener dos procesos, donde uno genera datos que deben ser procesados por el otro a medida que van siendo generados.

La función recibe el nombre de un archivo con tweets (uno por linea). La función recorre el archivo, produciendo un texto a la vez:

```
def sig_texto(nombre_archivo):
    """ Función generadora.
        En cada llamada retorna el texto de otro tweet.
    @param nombre_archivo El nombre del archivo de tweets.
    @yield El texto del tweet
    """
    with open (nombre_archivo) as tweets:
        for line in tweets:
            contenido=json.loads(line)
            if 'text' in contenido:
                yield contenido['text']
```

También necesitamos construir un diccionario con los sentimientos valorizados:

```
with open("sentimientos.txt") as sentimientos:
    valores = {}
    for linea in sentimientos:
        termino, valor = linea.split("\t")
        valores[termino.lower()] = int(valor)
```

Tomamos la precaución de reducir a minúscula el texto de los sentimientos.

Tenemos ahora que recorrer los tweets, separando cada texto en palabras, descartando todos los caracteres especiales (.,?-, etc) que puedan traera
pegadas. Eso lo hacemos con una expresión regular y `findall()`.

```
import re

palabra = re.compile("[\w]+")
```

Ahora recorremos los tweets valorizando cada palabra. Si el tweet tiene un valor distinto de cero, lo mostramos

```
for text in sig_texto('Tweets.json'):
    #   Por cada tweet.
    valor_tweet = 0
    #   Recorrer las palabras dentro del tweet
    for termino in palabra.findall(text):
        term = termino.lower()
        if term in valores:
            valor_tweet += valores[term]

    if valor_tweet > 0:
        print(valor_tweet, text)
```

**Comprobación**

Ahora, con todo junto, probemos

```
import json
import re

palabra = re.compile("[\w]+")
def sig_texto(nombre_archivo):
    """ Función generadora.
        En cada llamada retorna el texto de otro tweet.
    @param nombre_archivo El nombre del archivo de tweets.
    @yield El texto del tweet
    """
    with open (nombre_archivo) as tweets:
        for line in tweets:
            contenido=json.loads(line)
            if 'text' in contenido:
                yield contenido['text']

#
#   Cargar el diccionario de sentimientos.
#
with open("sentimientos.txt") as sentimientos:
    valores = {}
    for linea in sentimientos:
        termino, valor = linea.split("\t")
        valores[termino.lower()] = int(valor)

for text in sig_texto('Tweets.json'):
    #   Por cada tweet.
    valor_tweet = 0
    #   Recorrer las palabras dentro del tweet
    for termino in palabra.findall(text):
        term = termino.lower()
        if term in valores:
            valor_tweet += valores[term]

    if valor_tweet > 0:
        print(valor_tweet, text)
```

con este archivo de sentimientos:

```
love    1
amor    1
mariage 1
ugly    -1
happy   1
sincero 1
```

produce:

```
1 RT @byunghns:  I LOVE #틴탑 SO MUCH #쉽지않아 IS GOING TO BE SO GOOD 
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
1 RT @GossipRoomOff: Si Nathalie sait pertinemment que son couple ne va pas durer, alors pourquoi accepter la demande en mariage de Vivian ? …
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
1 RT @Nashgrier: Happy Birthday to one of my best friends @jackgilinsky Can't wait till you're out in LA! Have a good one!
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
2 RT @Positivamos: tudo o que eu quero é um amor sincero.
1 I thought I would be happy by now
1 RT @JeremiahTaylorr: happy birthday @MeghanNally ❤️❤️ imysm i found this in my dropbox http://t.co/NEFZJVWs6I
1 Happy Birthday to Robbie , @arsenalfantv you offer excellent insight &amp; coverage on The Mighty Arsenal hope you continue to expand &amp; Innovate
2 RT @Nashgrier: Happy birthday @tfionash I love you soooo much! Thank you for everything, you have no idea how much you mean to me. Hope it'…
```

Comment: muchas gracias, es justo lo que buscaba. Y por ejemplo para las palabras que no tienen un sentimiento dentro del tweet como podría asignarle el valor de todo el tweet a esa palabra?

Comment: No me queda clara tu pregunta. Un tweet tiene un montón de palabras; no todas son relevantes, supongo.

Comment: si, por ejemplo dentro de una línea de tweet hay algunas palabras que tienen X de valor(sentimiento) pero otras tienen 0 porque la palabra no aparece en el archivo de "sentimientos". ¿cómo podría asignar a esas palabras que valen cero el valor medio de la línea del tweet al que correspondan

Comment: Una vez determinado el valor del tweet, vuelves a recorrer todas sus palabras. Si la palabra no esta `valores`,la agregas ahi con el valor del tweet.

Comment: Muchas gracias!